# How to count the number of 0's in array using recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

Below is the code I've used . Its returning 0 as the count .What is the cause of error here?Is the base condition not adequate ?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int CountZeros(int a[], int n, int count) {
int i = 0;

  //base condition
  if (n == 0) return 0;
  if (a[0] == 0) {
    count += 1;
  }

  int SmallAns = CountZeros(a + 1, n - 1, count);
}
int main() {
  int count = 0;
  int a[5] = {
    1,
    0,
    3,
    0,
    5
  };
  CountZeros(a, 5, count);
  cout << count;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `count` is passed by value. Changes to it won't be visible from the outside

Comment: `CountZeros()` also falls off the end after calling itself recursively i.e. it returns without a `return` statement.  That causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: This task is utterly trivial without recursion. Why do you want to make it harder and slower?

Comment: If you really want to count zeroes, just use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count ; Or if this is an exercise, I don't see the point asking for a solution, but consider simplified example that counts number of times it was invoked: https://godbolt.org/z/eddWx7nzr

Comment: Maybe your issue is from using the non-standard `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.  I recommend only using relevant header files that you know the content of.

Comment: Nakul: If you found any answer that you liked you can say "thanks" in a few ways.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

Your function doesn't return anything in the recursive case, leading to undefined behaviour.
(Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions – if you don't `return` a value, no value is returned.)

You appear to be aiming for tail recursion, in which case the base case should return the accumulation argument (`count`), not a base value, and you make the initial call with the base value (zero):

```
int CountZeros(int a[], int n, int count) {

  if (n == 0) 
    return count;
  else 
    return CountZeros(a + 1, n - 1, a[0] == 0 ? count + 1 : count);
}
```

Using non-tail recursion, you would not pass `count` as an argument, but add to the recursive result:

```
int CountZeros(int a[], int n) {

  if (n == 0) 
    return 0;
  int SmallAns = CountZeros(a + 1, n - 1);
  return a[0] == 0 ? SmallAns + 1 : SmallAns;
}
```

This is less efficient, though – a decent compiler will turn the tail-recursive version into a simple loop (gcc, clang and msvc all do it).

Comment: ...or just: `if (n == 0) return 0; return a[0] == 0 + CountZeros(a+1, n-1);`

Comment: @JerryCoffin That boolean->integer conversion has confused so many beginners that I left it out. And if I'm not mistaken, you have a precedence bug...

Answer (score 1):

First task, when `n` equals zero the correct return value is `count` not `0`. I.e. you have reached the end of the array so you must return all the zeros you have counted so far. This is necessary because you add to your count before your recursive call.

```
if (n == 0) return count;
```

On the other hand if you added to the count after the recursive call then `return 0;` would be correct.

Second task, actually return something from the `CountZeros` function after you have made your recursive call.

```
int SmallAns = CountZeros(a + 1, n - 1, count);
return SmallAns;
```

Third task, use that returned value in the `main` function

```
count = CountZeros(a, 5, count);
cout << count;
```

Now, optional fourth task, there are a  lot of unneeded variables in this code. See if you can remove the `count` variable in `main` and the `smallAns` and `i` variables in `CountZeros`.

Comment: thank for such elaborate explanation